# Merging CSS and Applying primary styles to a div. Some Selectors do not work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to incorporate the CSS of a pricing table I found online. However it defines elements that conflict with elements of my theme in wordpress.

I've made a containing DIV `#rate-reset` with an ID and have applied most of the CSS and see that it is working.  However some web kit stuff is not.

I'm wondering if the following is valid?

```css
#rate-reset *,#rate-reset *::after,#rate-reset *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

#rate-reset html {
  font-size: 62.5% !important;
}

#rate-reset html* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale!important ;
}

#rate-reset body {
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
  color: #173d50 !important;
  background-color: #173d50 !important;
}
```

I inserted `#rate-reset` before the element selectors in an attempt to be specific, however they do not show up as computed styles when compared to the original demo.

Comment: `#rate-reset html*` is not valid CSS. An asterisk cannot immediately follow a simple selector. Also, I find it very unlikely that you will have an `html` or `body` element inside of `#rate-reset`. Perhaps you intended to write them in reverse order `html #rate-reset`?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rpnrIEEf4VeLeg58nJrd?p=preview) the correct css is:

```
#rate-reset *,
#rate-reset *::after,
#rate-reset *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5% !important;
}

html* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale!important ;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
  color: #173d50 !important;
  background-color: #173d50 !important;
}
```